# FIWARE NGSI LD install orion-ld on the windows machine

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Hi can you please help me with the steps to install FIWARE NGSI-LD on the Windows PC, I checked  the tutorials but its not working in windows

Comment: As written, your question doesn't seem to fit the [Stack Overflow Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) since there is insufficient information to [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would probably be better to raise this over at [GitHub](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Getting-Started/issues/new). However, you should start by checking that your current Windows machine has already fulfilled the minimum [prerequisites](https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#prerequisites)

Comment: It should be noted that the FIWARE tutorials do not start from scratch, and assume a minimal understanding of  Cygwin and Docker in order to run successfully on Windows.